# same left navigation bar at all site collection

Tags: navigation, site-collection, site

Can I have **the same left navigation bar** at SharePoint 2013 on all the subsites and site collections?

If it's not possible, can I do it with the navigation bar/Banner?

I'd like to use the same (default) menu on all of the SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done but the best would be to keep the Top Navigation the same across your entire site and have left/quick navigation site specific.

Customising both would be done by branding your site.

Read the below articles:

[Global Navigation](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Brand-SharePoint-Global-Navigation-The-Journey-Begins.aspx)

[Quicklaunch](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Brand-SharePoint-Quicklaunch-Getting-ready-to-expose-CSS-Part-1.aspx)